# Fine and acyclic sheaves on locales

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, sheaf-theory, grothendieck-topology

Hey all. Here's the thing, so I have a measure space. According to Johnstone's 'Topos theory' (page 213), let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space, we can define a Grothendieck pretopology on it (and hence a Grothendieck topology) if we take the poset $\Sigma$ of measurable sets on $X$ as a category and take the covering families to be the countable families of inclusions { $U_{i}\rightarrow U\mid i=1,2,3,...$ }, such that $\mu(U)-\mu(\overset{\infty}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcup}}U_{i})=0$. This site can be used to define sheaves of measurable functions on measure spaces (according to Dana Scott). What I wanted to do here was to define a fine sheaf that's acyclic on the resulting site and an injective resolution.

The measure space I'm working on is a Borel space whose underlying topological space is a discrete topological space, so therefore it's paracompact and Hausdorff. I wanted to know how the concepts of paracompact and Hausdorff would translate to the resulting Grothendieck topology, since I know that on a paracompact Hausdorff space a fine sheaf is acyclic. What I did was I've been looking at locales as the natural setting to deal with things like paracompactness and Hausdorffness on sites.

So my questions are:

1 - What the definition of a fine sheaf would be on a locale.

2 - I want to know if the definitions of paracompact and Hausdorff are in some way equivalent when going from topological spaces to locales, I want to know if I can ultimately define a fine sheaf that's acyclic on the resulting paracompact Hausdorff locale (in case it's in fact paracompact and Hausdorff too).

Anyone have a good reference? A good book on this?

Comment: Starting from a discrete space is not very interesting. As far as fine sheaf on a locale goes, have a look at the Voisin definition at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fine+sheaf. The definition of a partition of unity on a locale is probably what you are after, however, so this advice might be circular.

Comment: I don't think it addresses your question, but there is a thesis on measure theory and topoi by Matthew Jackson which you might find interesting: http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/students/jackson.pdf

Comment: Thank you both, I actually downloaded Matthew Jackson's thesis a while back, I know the discrete topological structure is in itself not interesting, but that's just the space I'm working on, really have to look deeper into that but it seems right from the point of view of what I need this whole construction for

Comment: If you have a measurable space X and some subspace Y⊂X, then functions on X are precisely arbitrary pairs of functions on Y and X\Y.  The same is true for morphisms of sheaves on X.  Therefore any sheaf on the site that you described is fine, flabby, and soft for trivial reasons.

Comment: Oh yeah, you mean the extension property for measurable spaces? The sheaf I'm working with is the sheaf of locally constant functions? Do locally constant functions extend to locally constant functions according to the property?

Comment: @Mario: I am not sure what do you mean by the extension property, but any measurable function defined on a measurable subset of a measurable space can be extended to a measurable function defined on the whole space by declaring it to be 0 outside of the original domain.  Locally constant functions stay locally constant under this transformation.

Comment: @Dimitri Pavlov: Are you meaning to say that the sheaf of locally constant functions on a topological space is flasque? I mean if I take a topological space and the Borel sigma-algebra generated by the topology and do what you're saying then every locally constant function would extend to a locally constant function outside of its definition domain and the sheaf would be flasque? I posted the question on Math Stack Exchange: http://bit.ly/pgyJbN. They're are saying that the sheaf of locally constant functions on a topological space is not necessarily flasque, I'm confused, thanks a bunch tho

Comment: @Mario: You asked a completely different question at MSE.  I have never mentioned arbitrary topological spaces in my comments.  Eric has also pointed this out at MSE in his reply to your comment.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong, my bad, now check this out: Let X and Y be finite-dimensional topological vector spaces. Let F be the sheaf of Y-valued locally constant functions. Let S1 and S2 be their Borel sigma-algebras respectivelly. Now since every measurable function $f$ defined on a measurable subset A of a measurable space can be extended to a measurable function f′ on X\A by defining it to be 0 (hence linear) on X\A, this means f′ is continuous as linear maps between finite-dimensional TVSs are continuous, so the sheaf of locally constant functions on X is flasque? in this case no?

Comment: @Mario: Yes, the sheaf of locally constant Y-valued (measurable) functions on the underlying measurable space of X is flasque.  I have no idea what do you mean when you say that f is linear (f was an arbitrary mesuarable function on A, why should it become linear when we extend it to X?).